# Doubts about recovering a .pem of an EC2 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, instance, pem

We are working with an EC2 instance in Amazon Web Services but we have lost our .pem.

In order to create a new one, we are following this guidance:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair

However, we are a bit worried because of this warning:

> When you stop an instance, the data on any instance store volumes is
>   erased. Therefore, if you have any data on instance store volumes that
>   you want to keep, be sure to back it up to persistent storage.

We cannot access the instance, therefore we cannot really make a proper backup. Instead, we have make a snapshot of the volumes in Elastic Block Store.

We are wondering if this is enough and we can indeed stop the instance to proceed to the pair key recover or we need to do something else in order not to lose any data.

Comment: What instance type are your instances? And are you _really_ using instance stores? They're not automatically mounted in most cases and unless you specifically make effort to do so, pretty much everything in EC2 defaults to being EBS-based (and if you are using only `t2`, `m4`, or `c4` instances, then you only have EBS storage). Also, if you have a snapshot of the volume, you can just create a new EBS volume from it and mount it to another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of instance. 
If it's EBS backed you are probably safe to proceed as the volume will be reattached. 
If it's instance store backed and you lost access to it you basically have lost what's on that machine.

By the sounds of it it's EBS backed. If it's instance store backed and you later created and attached an EBS volume and used that, you're going to be able to restore/reattach that volume just fine - but it's going to be to another machine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many instances we are talking about you should also be able to take an AMI Image of the running instance which will take snapshot of the EBS but also the exact state of the instance.

However if the instance's root device type is using a EBS backed store all the data should be safe so saving a snapshot and relaunching a new instance with the snapshot should have the data.

Good luck.